# Word for removing things from a shelf before cleaning

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a word or expression for removing everything (for example glasses, toothpaste, toothbrushes in a bathroom) from a shelf before cleaning the surface of the shelf?

For example, in a context like this:

The cleaning lady _____ the shelf before cleaning it.

Comment: Is there a problem with 'emptied'?

Comment: I think "cleared" would often be used.

Comment: @HotLicks I agreed with you so made it an answer (as it wasn't already said)

Comment: Yes, feel free to post any ideas as answers, even if they seem trivial to you. I haven't excluded any words as possible solutions. I just couldn't find the correct word for this meaning by googling.

Comment: an ELL candidate?!

Comment: @lbf Archetypal, I'd say.

Comment: What is wrong with "cleared off the shelf"?? I think you need the "off" here.....A policeman may clear the road, but a cleaning lady would clear off a shelf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am british and we would say

> The cleaning lady cleared the shelf before cleaning it

Clear is being used in this sense:

```
verb
1.    make or become clear, in particular:
2.    remove (an obstruction or unwanted item) from somewhere.
"Karen cleared the dirty plates"
```

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clear

but we would actually say

> The cleaner cleared the shelf before cleaning it.

as cleaning lady is very clunky

Comment: Quite so. It might have been a "cleaning gentleman"!

Comment: You need to cite your source for the definition.

Comment: @Laurel you mean a dictionary definition isn't good enough citation?

Comment: @WendyG No, I mean that you need to mention which dictionary you got the definition from (preferably with a link), as mentioned in the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: it was the useful google top entry, but I found exactly the same example in the newly added link